# Canvas move object in circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a rectangle in canvas, and I know how to move it up and sideways.
What I want to do is have it move in a circular motion.

So my objects(rectangle) x and y would go in a circle.

Now I am assuming I need a radius for how far out and some formula for the speed(1pixel)  to get it rotate on the axis.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The parametric equation for moving in a circle is this:

```
x=r*cos(theta)
y=r*sin(theta)
```

`theta` is the angle, and `r` the radius.

If you want to know the change in `theta` to get the desired speed, solving for the distance `d` you get that the change in `theta` is: `arccos(1-(d/r)^2/2)`

The JavaScript functions are [Math.cos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos), [Math.sin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin), and [Math.acos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/acos?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FMath%2Facos), respsectively. They all deal with radians.

Comment: Could you or someone provide me with a jsFiddle on how to add the math libs or how they are connected?

Comment: Here's a fiddle with fixes of markE's fiddle to make it work, and to show the calculation of the angle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cu6Zv/1/