# Move object around circle javascript

Tags: javascript, math, drag-and-drop, logic, farbtastic

[image]

Above is just image to get a link for fiddle its role is nothing in question.

I am trying to move an object along circle (actually a rectangular canvas with border-radius=100% so behaving as circle). But only able to move it and not able to resrict the movemment in the circle)

Here is my [**JS Fiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd8CB/1/). **Note:** Please scroll down in js code and view the only code  written under following comments

`//---- Code of interest begins-----//` to //---code of interest ends---//

My **desired output** will be like this wheel [farbtastic](http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/). Though it is open source yet i have been unable to use its mouse move event code in my colour wheel

While trying to search I found [Canvas move object in circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384663/canvas-move-object-in-circle)
but I can not use it because i do not know `d` and do not know what is `across`. So unable to get theta with `arccos(1-(d/r)^2/2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way I think is to calculate the angle and apply css3 rotate transform to an element.

I let you the example here..

Read the comments, specially on the rotate() function

http://jsfiddle.net/Z37FF/3/

HTML

```
    <body>
        <div id="circle">
        <div id="circle-in"></div>
        <div id="picker">
        <div id="picker-circle"></div>
        </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
```

CSS

```
    #circle{
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #000;
    }

    #circle-in{
        position: absolute;
        top: 35px;
        left: 35px;
        width: 230px;
        height: 230px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #fff;
    }

    #picker{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: -15px;
        width: 50%;

        /* important: sets the transform origin to the center of the circle */
        transform-origin: center left;
    }

    #picker-circle{
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #fff;
        margin: 0 3px 0 auto;
        cursor: move;
    }
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var circle = document.getElementById('circle'),
        picker = document.getElementById('picker'),
        pickerCircle = picker.firstElementChild,
        rect = circle.getBoundingClientRect(),

        center = {
            x: rect.left + rect.width / 2,
            y: rect.top + rect.height / 2
        },

        rotate = function(x, y){
            var deltaX = x - center.x,
                deltaY = y - center.y,

            // The atan2 method returns a numeric value between -pi and pi representing the angle theta of an (x,y) point.
            // This is the counterclockwise angle, measured in radians, between the positive X axis, and the point (x,y).
            // Note that the arguments to this function pass the y-coordinate first and the x-coordinate second.
            // atan2 is passed separate x and y arguments, and atan is passed the ratio of those two arguments.
            // * from Mozilla's MDN

            // Basically you give it an [y, x] difference of two points and it give you back an angle
            // The 0 point of the angle is right (the initial position of the picker is also right)

                angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI

            // Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) => [-PI +PI]
            // We must convert it to deg so...
            // / Math.PI => [-1 +1]
            // * 180 => [-180 +180]

            return angle
        },

        // DRAGSTART
        mousedown = function(event){
            event.preventDefault()
            document.body.style.cursor = 'move'
            mousemove(event)
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup)
        },

        // DRAG
        mousemove = function(event){
            picker.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotate(event.x, event.y) + 'deg)'
        },

        // DRAGEND
        mouseup = function(){
            document.body.style.cursor = null;
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup)
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)
        }



    // DRAG START
    pickerCircle.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown)

    // ENABLE STARTING THE DRAG IN THE BLACK CIRCLE
    circle.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
        if(event.target == this) mousedown(event)
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks.. Just great to see someone would help. But plz make sure the fiddle link is working.. It might be but ma unable to drag object any much

Comment: I'm sure that is because the fiddle only sets transform but not webkitTransform (in older chrome transform is not supported) try this one [http://jsfiddle.net/Z37FF/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Z37FF/1/)

Comment: Working in chrome but not following circle exactly

Comment: It's working fine in my pc.. Chrome 36 on Linux.
What is happening exactly?

Comment: I forget to prefix transform origin in css try it now.. [http://jsfiddle.net/Z37FF/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/Z37FF/2/)

Comment: :) That s really a worthy answer. Though I needed to do it with just keeping the position and not the transform(css) to make it working for even older browsers. Its fine with my chrome but not with even new firefox. Yet it very nice and full of effort answer.

Comment: well now i really finished it. It was not working in ff beacause of the event.x event.y, change it to event.pageX event.pageY.
transform is supported by almost all browsers... (not IE8 and lower)
see [http://caniuse.com/transforms2d](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d)
[http://jsfiddle.net/Z37FF/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/Z37FF/3/)

Comment: Hehe.. We have a joke in our language.. chal chal chottha her vari enj  e kehnda.(means... hey you liar! every-time you say like that) But you are true :) Its really now working fine as compatible for browsers as expected.. Thanks