# formula for changing speed of object moving in circle

Tags: javascript, geometry, linear-algebra

I am currently working moving different cars around a race track. I am using the formula listed in

[Canvas move object in circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384663/canvas-move-object-in-circle)

arccos (1- ( d ⁄ r ) <sup>2</sup> ⁄ 2 )

to vary the speed of the cars around the ends of the track and it works very well. What I don't understand is how the formula is derived. I have been working on trying to derive it from the second derivative of the arcsin or arccos but I can't get out the formula (so am guessing I'm walking the wrong path). Anyways, I am never comfortable using code I don't understand, so I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on it for me.

Comment: Did you see this example, here can you play with the parameters & values/.. to get a better understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Qnk5d/

Comment: This is purely a math question and has no relevance to programming; if you don't understand the derivation given by the answer in that linked post, you should probably ask on the [Math SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: How are you using this formula? For what?

Comment: Thank you @Lonely, yes I did see the jsfiddle and it is very helpful in visualizing it but I couldn't see how the formula was derived. MBo, I am animating some cars going around a track, think rectangle with semi-circles at each end. I was looking for a nice way of adjusting the speed of the cars around the semi-circles and this formula worked very nicely. meowgoesthedog - apologies for posting in the wrong forum, I just asked my question here because it originated from a coding context.

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the linked question, the movement of an object along a circle can be parametrized with a single angle `theta` which in loose terms describes how many "revolutions" the object has already made. Now, the question is for which angle `theta` the object is at Euclidean distance `d` from the initial (current) position A:

[image]

In other words, if you fix the time step `delta` of your simulation, the problem can be restated as to how one should adjust (increment) the angle so that the object displaces within the time interval `delta` to distance `d`.

From the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), one gets:

```
d^2 = r^2 + r^2 - 2*r*r*cos(theta) = 2*r^2*(1 - cos(theta))
```

Thus:

```
cos(theta) = 1 - 1/2*(d/r)^2

theta = arccos(1 - 1/2*(d/r)^2)
```

Comment: Thank you @ewcz, when I was reading the code I was thinking the distance was on the arc AC as opposed to the chord. Thank you for the diagram and derivation, it makes it very clear.